# QGIS crashes when geodatabase file opened

Tags: spatial-database, file-geodatabase, qgis-2.6

I recently updated my version of QGIS to 2.6 Brighton and am no longer able to open geodatabase files, everytime I try the program quits. Is there a way to fix this or is this a bug with the new version?